# Can I use two different versions of Google Play Api in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, google-play-services

I'm working on a android project that uses api Google Map and I have to use the old version 10.0.1 because **most my users use Google Service 10.**

1. Can I use the latest version of **FireBase (11.8.0)** along with the **Google Play Service 10.0.1**?
2. Can I have both old and new versions of Google Play Service together? (10.0.1 + 11.8.0)

Comment: if you develop app using *older version* it should vork on *new version* just fine. But I think that you should use same version of services (firbase and google play). But you can always try your own if it will wotk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you cannot. Both must be the same version.
2. No, you cannot. You can use only a single version.

And as a personal recommendation, always use the lastest version which is for the moment: `11.8.0`

Comment: You're right, but I'm compelled to use the old version 10.0.1, which is already compiled and usable without problems, I've used the old version.